# Disk usage irregularities

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage

can somebody please explain to me how is this possible?

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        204G  170G   24G  88% /

du -ah / | sort -rh | head -20
121G    /
88G /var
```

So, essentially my / folder is 121GB large (running all as the root user), but my hard drive is 170GB full?

Running the Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: this question has already been answered lots of time on so many website.

Answer (score 0):

`df` counts metadata towards the total disk usage while `du` only looks at the plain disk usage.